# Alternative image/film scanner software with support for Canon CanoScan 9000F

Tags: windows, windows-8, image-processing

The vendor-supplied driver and management software (MP Navigator EX) for my CanoScan 9000F are, to be kind, barely adequate. The UI is clumsy, non-intuitive, and provides poor workflow management. This makes it rather tiresome to use the scanner for large batch jobs.

Are there any alternatives to the Canon software which still provide access to the full set of features that the Canon scanner driver exposes? (Like doing preview scans, and specifying the media being scanned, resolution, exposure, dust-and-scratch filtering, etc)

It must work on Windows 8.1. If commercial it should be less than $150 and provide a free trial.

Answer (score 3):

**VueScan**, from [Hamrick Software](http://www.hamrick.com/).

[image]

It has a very intuitive interface. It has an easy, guided mode, or you can switch to advanced to adjust all of the settings. It has all of the usual scanning features, eg preview, setting the resolution, cropping etc. It can use the infrared light for dust/scratch removal, and it can do multiple passes at different exposures, which can get more detail from an image.

The Canoscan 9000F is on the list of [supported scanners](http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/supported-scanners.html)

VueScan costs $40 for basic version, or $80 for professional. You will need the professional version to use the advanced features. There is a free trial to download.

Comment: I did try this, but ultimately found the workflow to be no better than the Canon software, and in some cases worse.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7, don't know about 8, any scanner aware program has full featured access if you use the twain driver instead of Windows Image Acquisition (WIA). Screenshot of *Advanced Mode* tab with dust and scratches etc. below.  In previous versions of Windows (98/NT) I remember there being a way to invoke the twain driver directly, meaning you don't need any graphics program at all (and/or can use with any one). I can't find that route now, but I'm confident it's still there.

This means you should be able to twin up with something like [Xnview](http://www.xnview.com/) or [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) which have batch processing abilities. Some time will likely need to be spent on building the workflow that works for you, but it should work.

[image: Xnview "Select Twain source"]
[image: ScanGear advanced interface]

Host:
- Windows 7 x64 Home
- Canon LiDE 700f driver (64bit) downloaded and installed from Canon's support site this morning.